# How to generate QR Code to image using python qrcode library?

Tags: python, image

I want to make a QR Code to **image with text**.

This code works and leads only to text:

```
import qrcode

input_data = "Name\n\n"
descr = "\n\nDescription"

qr = qrcode.QRCode(
        version=1,
        box_size=10,
        border=5)

qr.add_data(input_data)
qr.add_data(descr)
qr.make(fit=True)

img = qr.make_image(fill='black', back_color='white')
img.save('qrcode001.png')
```

I tried opening image with open():

```
picture = Image.open("ita.png")
qr.add_data(picture)
```

But it's not working for me. How can I add a picture?

Comment: Have you read the [docs](https://pypi.org/project/qrcode/)?

Comment: Convert the image data to base64 string.

Comment: Yes, I've read the docs, but I couldn't found the answer.